# Geofire crashes when writing to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am writing a program to upload a LatLng data of the user to Firebase. It works by clicking a button **btnAddPickUpLocation** and it uploads to database. The user details and Uid has been initiated in other part of the codes and there is no issues with it.

The Lat Lng is currently hardcoded so it is not due to this variable source.

It returns perfectly when i set a Toast to return the Uid and it does not crash when i *comment out*

`mGeofire.setLocation(Uid, new GeoLocation(37.7853889, -122.4056973));`

Any idea what is wrong with this statement?

The relevant codes are as follows.

```
 RelativeLayout contentView = findViewById(R.id.contentView);
    btnAddPickUpLocation = contentView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddPickUpLocation);
    btnAddPickUpLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //AddPickUpLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

            String Uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello " + Uid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //addPickUpLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

            dbAddPickUpLocation = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Favourites");

            mGeofire = new GeoFire(dbAddPickUpLocation);

            mGeofire.setLocation(Uid, new GeoLocation(37.7853889, -122.4056973));

        }
```

Exception Details as follows

> 06-29 16:31:55.992 24528-24528/com.abc.getataxi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.abc.getataxi, PID: 24528
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setValue(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/firebase/tasks/Task; in class Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference' appears in /data/app/com.abc.getataxi-51bdN05Z7tlQu3bNLaX2nQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
>           at com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire.setLocation(GeoFire.java:182)
>           at com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire.setLocation(GeoFire.java:154)
>           at com.abc.getataxi.UserMainPage$2.onClick(UserMainPage.java:299)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Answer (score 1):

managed to solve it by a work around. For any guys looking, add a completion listener parameters like below.

```
mGeofire.setLocation(Uid, new GeoLocation(37.7853889, -122.4056973), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```